# How to bind table values using data-ng-start and end conditions in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I need to bind data with row values to a table, when i'm using the `data-ng-repeat-start` and `data-ng-repeat-end` data is not binding correct format.

```html
<table id="tbl"> 
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="data in RDetails" data-ng-if="Values(data)">
          <td data-ng-repeat-start="d in data.Dtls" data-ng-if="d.IsQStart && ValuesBL(d)">
              <span>{{d.V}}</span>
           </td>
          <td data-ng-if="d.IsQStart && ValuesBL(d)">
              <span>{{d.VP}}</span>
           </td>
           <td data-ng-if="ShowValuesBL(d)">
              <span>{{d.AV}}</span>
            </td>
           <td data-ng-repeat-end="d in data.Dtls" data-ng-if="Values(d)">
             <span>{{d.AVP}}</span>
           </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

when I use the above condition table showing the same values how can i do this. Where i did mistake please help me on this [Please see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBrpd.png) i am getting repeated values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly - just presenting content of every `RDetails.Dtls` element as a table row - here is solution:

```
<table id="tbl"> 
    <tbody data-ng-repeat="data in RDetails">
      <tr data-ng-repeat="d in data.Dtls" data-ng-if="Values(data)">
          <td data-ng-if="d.IsQStart && ValuesBL(d)">
              <span>{{d.V}}</span>
           </td>
          <td data-ng-if="d.IsQStart && ValuesBL(d)">
              <span>{{d.VP}}</span>
           </td>
           <td data-ng-if="ShowValuesBL(d)">
              <span>{{d.AV}}</span>
            </td>
           <td data-ng-if="Values(d)">
             <span>{{d.AVP}}</span>
           </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```